# What does $P(A \triangle B)$ mean?

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

I know its a simple question but its hard to google these symbols. Anyways, anyone care to explain what $P(A \triangle B)$ means? I haven't seen this symbol before and I'm not sure on how to interpret it.

Answer (score 4):

The triangle is almost certainly being used to for *symmetric difference*:

$$A\mathrel{\triangle}B=(A\setminus B)\cup(B\setminus A)=(A\cup B)\setminus(A\cap B)\;.$$

The $P$ might be the power set operator, in which case the whole thing is the set of all subsets of $A\mathrel{\triangle}B$:

$$P(A\mathrel{\triangle}B)=\{X:X\subseteq A\mathrel{\triangle}B\}.$$

However, a script $P$ is more often used for this purpose, and as has just been pointed out to me, you used the [probability](/questions/tagged/probability) tag, so $P(A\mathrel{\triangle}B)$ is probably the probability assigned to the subset $A\mathrel{\triangle}B$ of your sample space.

Comment: Since the topic is "probability" it's more likely that $P$ is the probability measure of the event.

Comment: @Graham: I’ve an unfortunately tendency to overlook the tags. You’re absolutely right, and I’ve revised the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

As in other post, $A\bigtriangleup B$ is the symmetric difference of 2 sets. $P(A\bigtriangleup B)$ is the probability that at least one of $A$ and $B$ but not both happens, i.e. exactly one of $A$ and $B$ happens.